# Изменить Title на странице со статичным head, но инклудными body

Tags: php

Бьюсь весь вечер, нужно изменить Title на странице со статичным head, но инклудными body. Тоесть название страницы есть в body, а сам body заинклужен в хеадере. include('body.php');

Просьба не писать, что включи наоборот хеадер в боди таким кодом и всё заработает:

```
$header = "title of my page";
include 'header.php';
echo ("$header"); // на месте тайтла
```

Нужно сделать именно при **include 'body.php';**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = $('элемент из которого берем имя титла').html();     document.title = data.replace( /([\s\S]+)<title>/, '' ).replace(/<\/title>([\s\S]+)/, '' );
```

А если вам нужно решение на пыхах, то только тот вариант, который вам не нравится